# count number of files failed to move using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I am using the following script to count the number of files move to the destination folder.

```
while read ln; do mv -v $ln $dest_path1 2>>log;((count++));done
```

Now the problem is that I have no idea how many files are successfully moved and how many are failed. Can anyone tell me how to do it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Replace your script with this:

```
count=0
while read ln; do
    mv -v $ln $dest_path1 2>>log && ((count++))
done
```

Now becaue `&&` operator counter increment will happen only when `mv` command is successful.

Answer (score 1):

It'd be easier if you keep track of the return code instead.

```
success=0
fail=0
while read ln; do
  mv -v $ln $dest_path1 2>>log && ((success++)) || ((fail++))
done
echo "Number of files moved: ${success}"
echo "Number of files not moved: ${fail}"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, I have no idea why the no. of fail will always return 1?